# Can we set value Yes when the checkbox is check and No when its not check

Tags: angular

**My thought**
I am new angular and i'm trying to develop a angular code that when the checkbox is checked i want to set value to Yes and when its not check i want to set it to No. I'm not using ngmodel i'm using formcontrolname. ill leave my code below

**TScode**

```
changeStatus(event:Event){
    const isChecked = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).checked;
    console.log(isChecked)
}
```

**html**
If i need to add any code please help me

```
<mat-checkbox matinput formControlName="substanceAbuseAlcohol" color="primary" (change)="changeStatus($event)">Alcohol</mat-checkbox><br>
```

**form**

```
this.patientPastHistoryForm = new FormGroup({
      patientId: new FormControl(this.clientId),
      substanceAbuseAlcohol: new FormControl(''),
});
```

Comment: Note matinput is redundant on a `mat-checkbox`. See the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using mat-check box you can use the event `change` and the property `checked`

```
<mat-checkbox  
      (change)="patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseAlcohol').setValue(
        $event.checked ? 'Yes' : 'No')"
      [checked]="patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseAlcohol').value=='Yes'" >
   Alcohol
</mat-checkbox>
```

NOTE and Personal opinion: in a real Project or in a simple exercise create a custom form control using ControlValueAccesor should be only to create a more complex component, if only is change "the aspect" of a check-box I consider unnecessary (else you need use this "special checkbox" in several several components)

**Update**

NOTE: Is an answer to the comment about three check-box relationated -really should be in another question-

When we has tree check box relationated we can do something like

```
<mat-checkbox  
      (change)="$event.checked && patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseAlcohol').setValue('Yes') &&
patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseDrugs').setValue('Yes')
"
      [checked]="patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseAlcohol').value=='Yes' &&
patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseDrugs').value=='Yes' " >
   Substance Abuse
</mat-checkbox>


<mat-checkbox  
      (change)="patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseAlcohol').setValue(
        $event.checked ? 'Yes' : 'No')"
      [checked]="patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseAlcohol').value=='Yes'" >
   Alcohol
</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox  
      (change)="patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseDrugs').setValue(
        $event.checked ? 'Yes' : 'No')"
      [checked]="patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseDrugs').value=='Yes'" >
   Drugs
</mat-checkbox>
```

Well, when we has so many code in .html is time to translate the code to the .ts. So create three functions

```
checkAll()
{
    this.patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseAlcohol').setValue('Yes')
    this.patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseDrugs').setValue('Yes')
}

change(nameControl:string,checked)
{
    this.patientPastHistoryForm.get(nameControl).setValue(
        checked ? 'Yes' : 'No')"
}

parseValue(nameControls:string[])
{
    let checked:boolean=true;
    nameControls.forEach(x=>{
       checked=checked && this.patientPastHistoryForm.get(x).value=='Yes'"

    })
    return checked;
}
```

See that the function "parseValue" received an array of string. He loop over this array and return if all values are Yes true, else false

And our .html use this functions

```
<mat-checkbox  
      (change)="$event.checked && checkAll()"
       [checked]="parseValue(['substanceAbuseAlcohol','substanceAbuseDrugs'])>
   Substance Abuse
</mat-checkbox>


<mat-checkbox  
      (change)="change('substanceAbuseAlcohol',$event.checked)"
      [checked]="parseValue(['substanceAbuseAlcohol'])" >
   Alcohol
</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox  
      (change)="change('substanceAbuseDrugs',$event.checked)"
      [checked]="parseValue(['substanceAbuseDrugs'])" >
   Drugs
</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: Thanks this works too, But can we give default value No

Comment: Just replace the setValue by `$event.checked ? 'No' : 'Yes'` and checked by `!patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseAlcohol').value=='No'"`. The idea is always the same, (change) change the value of the FormControl and [check] is true or false according the value of the FormControl

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I have one question. Lets say i have  three checkbox A  as a parent and B and C as child checkbox. when i check either B or C the parent checkbox A is automatically check and when i check parent checkbox A both the child B and C checkbox is checked. how can i achieve that. the values are same with the above code.

Comment: @SanamahiChannel, update the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I have tried the above codes i dont  know why when i check the substance abuse alcohol and drugs doesn't check. Can i get a stackblitz demo

Answer (score 0):

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5mfkyz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Slightly hacky but following works using a variable in the html

```
  <mat-checkbox
    color="primary"
    (change)="
      patientPastHistoryForm.controls['substanceAbuseAlcohol'].setValue(
        saveValue.checked ? 'Yes' : 'No'
      )
    "
    #saveValue
  >
    Alcohol
  </mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: This works fine in this case. However, in a real project, you should use ControlValueAccessor (https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor), and create a custom control with whatever behaviour you need.

Comment: ^^^^^ 100% agree

Comment: can we check checkbox if i received "Yes" from api and uncheck when i received "No"