# How to check checkbox base on Value received

Tags: angular

**Understanding**
Lets say i received value "Yes" and "No". My question is i want to check the checkbox only when i received "Yes".

**codes that i tried**

```
<section class="pleft ptop" *ngFor="let item of patientPastMedicalHistoryList">
              <mat-checkbox color="primary"
              (change)="patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseAlcohol').setValue(
                $event.checked ? 'Yes' : 'No')" 
                checked="{{item.substanceAbuseAlcohol ==='Yes'}}" 
               >Alcohol</mat-checkbox><br>
              </mat-form-field>
</section>
```

**I have tried**
This doesnt help. Below code always check the checkbox even when the value received is "NO"

[checked]="patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseAlcohol').value=='Yes'"

```
 checked="{{item.substanceAbuseAlcohol ==='Yes'}}"
```

**form**

```
this.patientPastHistoryForm = new FormGroup({
      patientId: new FormControl(this.clientId),
      substanceAbuseAlcohol: new FormControl(''),})
```

**data**

```
 patientPastMedicalHistoryList: Array<PatientPastMedicalHistoryModel>=[];
```

**This is how i fetch the value**

```
  getPatientPastHistoryList() {
    debugger
    this.clientsService.getPatientPastHistoryList(this.clientId)
      .subscribe(
        (response: ResponseModel) => {
          if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            this.patientPastMedicalHistoryList = response.data;                                
          } else {
            this.patientPastMedicalHistoryList = [] ;           
          }
          this.patientPastHistoryForm.patchValue({
            ...response.data,
          })
        });
  }
```

**Received data**

```
{
  "expires_in": 0,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "patientId": 2143,
      "substanceAbuseAlcohol": "No",
      "substanceAbuseMarijuana": "Yes",
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we set value Yes when the checkbox is check and No when its not check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72395899/can-we-set-value-yes-when-the-checkbox-is-check-and-no-when-its-not-check)

Comment: This is in Eliseo's answer to your previous question

Comment: Sorry no it doesnt help.

Comment: i have tried both.That codes always check the checkbox even if i received value Yes or No

Comment: You don't have any code patching the recieved data to the form?

Comment: i have treid using this.patientPastHistoryForm.patchValue({
            ...response.data,
          })   this doesnt help.i have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5mfkyz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

`response.data` is an array

you want `this.patientPastHistoryForm.patchValue({ ...response.data[0], })`

Comment: thanks a lot it works when i add response.data[0]

Comment: im new to angular please do help me in this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72405197/how-to-automatically-check-checkbox-b-and-c-when-we-check-checkbox-a?noredirect=1#comment127910705_72405197

Comment: (change)="$event.checked && patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseAlcohol').setValue('Yes') &&
            patientPastHistoryForm.get('substanceAbuseMarijuana').setValue('Yes')"    --this line of code is not setting the value "Yes" for Marijuana but its setting value for alcohol  any reason